# Connect QGIS to Esri geodatabase hosted on RDBMS (PostgreSQL)

Tags: qgis, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase

I have an ArcGIS 10.5.1 enterprise geodatabase hosted on PostgreSQL 9.4 (non-PostGIS enabled, but with `SDE.ST_Geometry` support). I'd like to add some feature classes as layers in QGIS. How can I do this?

Comment: This question is a bit confusing. "Geodatabase" is a term that refers to a database where an Esri geometry datatype has been added (or an RDS node with PostGIS enabled, where the Esri SDE tables have been populated).  Do you have SDE.ST_Geometry enabled in this database?  Not enabling PostGIS removes one of the most popular geometry column solutions from your options (and QGIS support, too, I think).

Comment: It's an Enterprise geodatabase. Yes, I've copied the st_geometry library to the postgres server and it should be sde.st_geometry enabled

Comment: I think you may be right, it looks like QGIS may only support connecting to PostGIS enabled Postgres databases.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the exact version of PostgreSQL and the exact version of ArcGIS geodatabase.

Comment: I've updated the question to include the version numbers of Postgres and the ArcGIS geodatabase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible - you need to use real PostGIS geometries instead.

Comment: It looks like I can only use the PostGIS template when initially running the Create Enterprise Geodatabase tool. So I'm thinking, I could create a new db, and copy my feature classes over to the new, PostGIS enabled Enterprise geodatabase. Or is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

In QGIS open the Data Source Manager, click PostgreSQL on the left, add a new connection, fill out the database connection details:

[image]

Once that's added click Connect. Once you're all connected up you can add any layers you want.

Comment: If it isn't PostGIS enabled I think you should click on "Also list tables with no geometry", otherwise you may not see any layer in de DB.

Comment: Thank you for the clear directions. I put in my connection info for my database and clicked "test connection" and it succeeds. When I add the connection and click Connect however, it says "Retrieving tables of <database name>..." and I cannot add layers successfully to the canvas

Comment: I also tried checking the option "Also list tables with no geometry"